# Google Apps Script- Get Guest List from Calendar

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am having a hard time finding a way to get the emails of all the partecipants in the next events on my calendar.

I only get the email of only one partecipant

The final idea should be to color code the calendar based on who is in the meetings.

Here's what I got so far

````
  var today = new Date();
  var nextweek = new Date();
  nextweek.setDate(nextweek.getDate() + 7);
  Logger.log(today + " " + nextweek);

  var calendars = CalendarApp.getAllOwnedCalendars(); 
  Logger.log("found number of calendars: " + calendars.length); 



  for (var i=0; i<calendars.length; i++) { 
    var calendar = calendars[i];           
    var events = calendar.getEvents(today, nextweek); 
    for (var j=0; j<events.length; j++) {
      var e = events[j];
      var title = e.getTitle();
      var guestlist=events[j].getGuestList();
      var details=guestlist[j].getEmail();


        if (details == "example0@gmail.com") {
        e.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.CYAN);
      }
      if (details == "example1@gmail.com") {
        e.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.YELLOW);
      }
      if (details == 'example2@gmail.com') {
        e.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.GREEN);
      }
    }
  }
} ```
````

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: Hi! The issue was that I could not get the emails of all partecipants (e.g. If there were 3 guests, my output was only 1 email of the 3). I was trying to get all of them.

By the way I found a solution! :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `By the way I found a solution!`, I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.